# MFC CWnd height and width

Tags: c++, mfc, cwnd

How do you get the height and width of a CWnd*? The CWnd is the window correct? Why isn't the command:

```
CWnd* parent = this->GetParent(); // C++ command
parent->GetSize(); // what I think the method should be OR ...
parent->GetWindowRect(); // what i think it should be (no arguments)
```

what is this LPRECT? I already have the object ... why and what is the argument going into GetWindowRect? What am I pointing to? I already have the object i want to find the size of ... just give me the size.

Comment: There is not `GetSize` method in the `CWnd` class. And the `GetWindowRect` method needs a parameter which is the pointer to the rectangle where the position and the size of your window will go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `LPRECT` parameter is a pointer to a [`RECT` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5ch4fda.aspx) (the "LP" prefix actually stands for "long pointer", for historical reasons).

The [`GetWindowRect` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3ef9c0s.aspx) is going to retrieve the window rectangle for your `CWnd` object, but it's going to do so by filling in a `RECT` structure with those coordinates. Therefore, you need to create a `RECT` structure and pass a pointer to it to the `GetWindowRect` function.

It is worth mentioning that the API accepts a pointer to a `RECT` structure for full compatibility with Win32. The [`CRect` MFC class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h58f4c7y.aspx) actually *inherits* from the `RECT` structure defined by the SDK, so you can use a `CRect` object interchangeably here. Which is nice, because `CRect` provides member functions that make it easier to manipulate rectangles.

Sample code:

```
CWnd* pwndParent = this->GetParent();

CRect rc;
pwndParent->GetWindowRect(&rc);

// rc now contains the rectangle of your window!
```

Note that the `GetWindowRect` function will return the *screen* coordinates of your window. This is usually not what you want, unless you're trying to reposition the window on the screen. Screen coordinates are tricky to work with because they are relative to the entire virtual screen, which can have negative coordinates in a multi-monitor configuration. Also, if you try and determine the size of the window using its screen coordinates, you'll get the entire size of the window on the screen, including its non-client areas (like the title bar, the min/max/close buttons, etc.).

What you normally want instead are the *client* coordinates of a window, retrievable by calling the [`GetClientRect` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkzy4k3x.aspx) in an identical manner. This time, we'll use a `RECT` structure, just because we can:

```
CWnd* pwndParent = this->GetParent();

RECT rcClient;
pwndParent->GetClientRect(&rcClient);
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer is you use `GetWindowRect`.

```
CWnd* parent = this->GetParent();
CRect size;
parent->GetWindowRect(&size);
```

If you are asking *why* it is done like that, I can think of two answers:

1. MFC is *very* old (older than some of the people reading this I suspect).  Compilers couldn't handle returning structures by value in those days.  Since then "backwards compatability".
2. MFC is (or at least, was originally) a *very* thin wrapper over the Windows API functions.

Comment: You're right about the reason being MFC's age, but I don't think it was ignorance about how to write things. It was technical limitations of early C++ compilers that didn't do very well with returning structures from functions. You were expected to pass a *pointer* to a large structure, both for speed and compatibility reasons. I wasn't actually around then, but I remember hearing that the early compilers only let you return a value that could fit into a processor register. RVO hadn't been invented yet.

Comment: Cody Gray: Ah yes.  It's all coming back to me.  (I'm afraid I *was* around in those days.  I first met MFC in about 1994.)

Comment: nice history background. Helps to understand why things are the way they are.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I figured out my answer I believe. Here for anyone who cares to know ...

```
CRect rc_total_window;
this->GetWindowRect(rc_total_window);
```

where 'this' is a CWnd* object. Thanks again for all the history and explanation. It helps to know why things are the way they are so you can be sure that you aren't doing something wrong; especially helps when the methodology is different than what was learned in modern language courses.

Comment: You need an `&` in front of `rc_total_window`.

Comment: Are you sure Martin that I need a '&' before the rc_total_window? I just ran the code and it returned back values for top, left, bottom and right. Perhaps differences in versions.

Comment: The documentation I found doesn't mention an overload, but I think there is one for a `Rect &` on which case you don't.

Comment: @MartinBonner: There is no overload for `GetWindowRect` taking a `CRect&`. The `CRect` class, however, implements an [operator LPRECT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1wyf0b2.aspx), that is implicitly invoked when passing a `CRect` object to a method expecting an `LPRECT` argument.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again for the explanation.